# Git - Undo checkout

Tags: git

I'm having heart attack right now.
A month ago I'm clonned a commit to master, and when I was opening PowerShell console, I was seeing

```
C:\Workspace\Project [(abcd12...)]>
```

Today I commited changes and ran command

```
git checkout master
```

I have missed it with another command and thought it will place changes to master, but it replaced old content with new.

Is these a way to find last commit and put it to my disk and master? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: I would have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit,
but you are looking for git revert <commit no>, followed by another checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see a list of the historical changes to your repository, you can use [`git reflog`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html)

You can then do [`git show <commitish>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) to find the commit you want to restore and do a [`git reset --hard <commit>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) or a [`git checkout <commit>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) to any of the commits listed in the reflog.